# Rails link_to and merge parameter into existing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `link_to` directive that adds a link to an icon by passing a block to `link_to`. What I'm trying to do is merge existing query parameters in the URL and append this one as well if it is clicked. Syntax seems broken:

```
<%= link_to {params:params.merge({foo: bar })}, title: 'Title of my icon' do %>
   <i class="myicon"></i>
<% end %>
```

what's the correct way to write the `link_to` above to merge my foo query parameter into the existing query parameters in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
<%= link_to url_for(params.merge(foo: bar)), title: 'Title of my icon' do %>
  <i class="myicon"></i>
<% end %>
```